# Distribution of the ratio of $2$ dependent Gamma R.V.

Tags: probability, gamma-distribution

If $X_i \sim \Gamma(\alpha_i,\beta_i)$ are dependent Gamma random variables ( $i=1,2$), what is the distribution of $\dfrac{X_1}{X_2}$?

Comment: @JimmyR. my variables are dependent.

Comment: If dependent then nothing can be said about it. What we need then is their joint distribution.

Comment: @drhab, how do I find their joint distribution?

Comment: As long as you only know that the $X_i$ are dependent Gamma variables it is impossible to "find" their joint distribution (hence also impossible to find the distribution of $X_1/X_2$). So "they" cannot ask you to find it unless more information about their relation has been handed over to you.

Comment: @drhab, How about the moment generating function?

Comment: See my former comment. **Nothing** can be done as long as you give no information about the joint distribition.